# How does one deal with IDisposable fixture members in MSTest?

Tags: c#, mstest

I have a test class which has some IDisposable items inside of it. This was my first attempt at doing something like this:

```
private MemoryStream toolExampleMs;
private MemoryStream issueClassExampleMs;
private MemoryStream issueTypeExampleMs;
private MemoryStream uniqueIdExampleMs;

private Check exampleCheck;

public SuppressionDatabaseTest()
{
    this.toolExampleMs = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toolExample));
    this.issueClassExampleMs = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toolExample));
    this.issueTypeExampleMs = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(issueTypeExample));
    this.uniqueIdExampleMs = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(uniqueIdExample));

    this.exampleCheck = new Check();
    this.exampleCheck.IssueClass = "FooBarClass";
    this.exampleCheck.IssueType = "FooBarType";
    this.exampleCheck.Key = "FooBarExactWith?Unicode";
}

[ClassCleanup]
public void CleanupAll() // Error: CleanupAll has the wrong signature
{
    toolExampleMs.Dispose();
    issueClassExampleMs.Dispose();
    issueTypeExampleMs.Dispose();
    uniqueIdExampleMs.Dispose();
}

[TestCleanup]
public void Cleanup()
{
    this.toolExampleMs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    this.issueClassExampleMs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    this.issueTypeExampleMs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    this.uniqueIdExampleMs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
}
```

Unfortunately, the ClassCleanup method must be `static` in MSTest, which means there's no place to hook the calls to dispose. Does this mean I need to reconstruct these streams before and after every individual test?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to? The streams shouldn't be used to store or pass information between tests; no matter what setup and teardown may be required for each test or all tests, the tests should be theoretically order-independent. What order they actually run in, whether it's alphabetical, as defined or fully random, should make no difference, and no test should depend on another test having been successful.

Comment: @KeithS: The streams do not get modified by any of the tests. Just seemed wasteful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is yes. You will need to reconstruct these streams before each test and dispose them after each test. This is easy with the [TestCleanup] and [TestInitialize] attributes.

So instead of constructing your streams in your test class: SuppressionDatabaseTest use [TestInitialize]